# Android and iOS: show push notification only for selected criteria

Tags: android, ios, push-notification

Based on specific criteria, I want to show to the user Push Notification or not. For example, User is in a specific region. In this case I want only show to the user Push Notifications that are for its region. If a Push Notification is for an other region, the Push will not be shown.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible in different way,

1. you can notify your server by sending some parameter based on your criteria for not to send notification.
2. You can use `unregisterForRemoteNotificationTypes` to unregister for remote notification based on your circumstances, you have to register it again to get notifications back using `registerForRemoteNotifications`.
3. If you are using firebase then you can use

   `Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "yourNotification")`

   `Messaging.messaging().unsubscribe(fromTopic: "yourNotification")`